# How to make a pint script same the original Volume indicator but add Multi line moving average volume?

Tags: pine-script

How to make a pint script the same as the original Volume indicator but add Multiline moving average volume?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is only an imperfect solution that requires you to set the bottom margin to 0 under your chart settings.

```
//@version=4
study("Volume", overlay = true,  scale = scale.none)

scalingFactor = input(8, title = "volume scaling factor")

hh = highest(volume, 100) * scalingFactor

plot(hh, color = #00000000)

ma1 = sma(volume, 30)
ma2 = ema(volume, 60)
ma3 = ema(volume, 90)

plot(volume, style = plot.style_columns, color = volume >= volume[1] ? color.green : color.red)

plot(ma1, color = color.red)
plot(ma2, color = color.yellow)
plot(ma3, color = color.aqua)
```